# How to convert in c# date if date month is text

Tags: c#, datetime

Best way of converting date like "December 6, 2011" to pattern like "yyyy-MM-dd" ?

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact("December 6, 2011", "MMMM d, yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: Also good example, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MMMM d, yyyy` format with an *english-based* culture like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

```
string s = "December 6, 2011";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MMMM d, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); // 2011-12-06
}
```

[`"MMMM"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#MMMM_Specifier) represents the full name of the month based on culture settings.